# Office 2010 and save issues

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-excel-2010

Since I installed office 2010 I can't save an Excel file that I used under Excel 2003.

[image]

what to do?

Comment: Can you save the Excel file using Excel 2003? It could just be a coincidence, the file could be corrupted.

Comment: @taspeotis: I don't understand. I installed 2010, so 2003 does not exist anymore...

Comment: Go to another computer, with a copy of Excel 2003.

Comment: @taspeotis: and what should I copy to the other computer, man, if I can't save? :( I don't need the old file, I need my modifications.

Comment: @serhio did you try saving it in 2010 format ?

Comment: @Shark: I tried saving in xls, xlsx, xlsm... same result.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to create a new spreadsheet make changes and save it ?
If you can , I suggest you create a new file and copy-paste the contents of the existing file into it and save it .